# In GKE, typeorm fails to connect to Google Cloud SQL proxy

Tags: sql, cloud, nestjs, google-kubernetes-engine, typeorm

Please go to https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/8000 to see the details of this error.

Answer (score 0):

Need to upgrade "pg" to v8.0+
This issue is fixed.

Comment: Congrats! Since you've solved the issue can you set this answer as **Accepted Answer**. Thanks!